# getting specific index from sql

Tags: sql

I'm trying to pull from my sql database without having to load it into a var and pulling the items I want with a for loop.

How can I get the 5 items in the 5th index
"               " 5 "          " 10th index...

This is what I'm doing not it's way to hackish.

```
function get_db(a) {
 index_count=a

 db.transaction(
  function(tx) {

  var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Greeting');
  var r=""

  if (up_check === 0){
      index_count = index_count +4
        }
        r += rs.rows.item(index_count).salutation + ": " + rs.rows.item(index_count).salutee + "\t\t"
   })
return r
}
```

I'd ideally want to get something like

```
var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM index_count (and the next for items) Greeting');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're SQL Server 2005 or above you can use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Something like this (freehand):

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [youordercolumns]) AS [RowNum]
FROM [youtable]    
WHERE [RowNum] BETWEEN @index AND @index + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what Database Server you are using.

For example, MySQL supports a very simple but non-standard solution:

```
SELECT * FROM Greeting
LIMIT 5 OFFSET yourStartingIndex
```

Other servers support one or more ways of performing a 'limit with offset'.

The SQL standard provides three ways:

- Using OFFSET and FETCH FIRST:(since SQL:2008)

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM Greeting 
> OFFSET yourStartingIndex ROWS 
> FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
> ```

- Using a Window function:(since SQL:2003)

> ```
> SELECT * FROM (
>   SELECT
>     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YourOrderColumns ASC) AS rownum,
>     columns
>   FROM tablename
> ) AS foo
> WHERE rownum > yourStartingIndex AND rownum <= (4+yourStartingIndex)
> ```

- Using a cursor:

> ```
> DECLARE cursor-name CURSOR FOR ...
> OPEN cursor-name
> FETCH RELATIVE number-of-rows-to-skip ...
> CLOSE cursor-name
> ```

LINKS: http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-limit-offset